# Displaying cmd.exe window inside a Qt widget

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qwidget, qtgui

I have this requirement of launching a CLI (Command Line Interface) based tool (similar to cmd.exe) from inside a Qt widget, so that user can interact with this CLI from inside the widget. The only alternative I have with me is to use a QProcess and launch myprog.exe, but in that case, it'll have a separate window. What i want basically is command line embedded inside a QTabWidget. What would be the best way to do the same?

Comment: This kind of question is more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have succesfully launched a command line program from QProcess, using setProcessChannelMode and the readyRead() signal, without it showing in a separate window.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Bgie: The problem is : I want the console based myprog.exe to be embedded inside one of the tabs of my QTabWidget. To be more precise, the console window should be acting like a child widget of my Tab bar. Functionality should be the same, viz. accepting commands from the user, executing them and displaying the output in the embedded console window.

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box solution for that. You would need to write that widget yourself. I used a simple textedit, with a button next to it to send input, and a plain text box to display the output.

Comment: I'll try that out Bgie! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There are several out-of-box solutions like [QTermWidget](https://github.com/zester/Quantum/tree/master/QTermWidget) or [QConsole](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qconsole/). You would not need to write that widget yourself.

Here is an example how to use this:

```
console = new QTermWidget();

QFont font = QApplication::font();
font.setFamily("Monospace");
font.setPointSize(12);

console->setTerminalFont(font);
console->setScrollBarPosition(QTermWidget::ScrollBarRight);
console->setColorScheme("WhiteOnBlack");

ui->tabWidget->insertTab(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex(), console, QString(QDir::currentPath()));
```

There is little to no sense to reinvent your own solution as suggested in the comments.